# Using DePo Masthead with WP 3+

Tags: themes, wp-admin

Does anyone have any experience with running [DePo Masthead](http://powazek.com/posts/1182) in WP3+?  I'm thinking of changing the theme on my [personal site](http://chasrmartin.com) and [blog](http://explorations.chasrmartin.com).

Comment: Which *major version* of WordPress, specifically? "WordPress 3+" isn't specific enough to identify specific compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [DePo Clean](http://powazek.com/depo-clean) in the past and assuming that its coded the same i can say it is very light weight and easy to customize and worked just fine on WordPress 3.0.4 as far as i can tell.